# Passing arguments to the constructor of an array

Tags: c++, class

My code looks like this

```cpp
#include <iostream>

class area {
private:
  double data;

public:
  area(double data);
};

area::area(double data) { this->data = data; }

int main() {
  area areas[2]; //here's the problem

  return 0;
}
```

It's not supposed to do anything in particular other than me trying to fiddle with classes.

I can either create
`area areas[2];` or `area areas(arguments);` Is there even a way to do both of them at the same time? I know you can create an array and then use separate function.

Comment: You can use an initializer list (`area areas[2] = {area(1.0), area(2.0)};`)

Comment: If you can modify the class then give data a default arguement